# Does playing with a "default" weapon set-up in MW3 unlock weapon proficiencies?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

If you have the weapon in the default weapon class is it able to earn proficiencies? 
OR earn points towards the same weapon if you've earned it in rank?

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you're asking here - are you asking "If you are using any of the non-custom default classes, do you still earn progress toward weapon proficiencies?"  What exactly do you mean by "earn points towards the same weapon if you've earned it in rank?"

Comment: If you use the default non-custom weapon for MW3 and you also have same weapon unlocked, does the non-custom default class version of the weapon still earn the proficiencies for the weapon type...

Answer (score 4):

Playing with weapons before unlocking them does not help leveling up. after they are unlocked, it does regardless of how you pick them up